# Standard opportuny list and governor limit

Tags: list-view

This may be a simple question. I am trying to bulk update user selected opportunities. I was thinking of following a technique similar to the example in the online docs : "Mass-Updating Records with a Custom List Controller".

The only questions I had were:

1. Will this work if the user selects more than 50000 opportunities by going to the Standard "All Opportunities" view?
2. Do the governor limits apply to standard list views of accounts/opportunities, etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable in batch Apex.

1. Batch Apex can handle millions of records, but not standard Apex or Set Controllers.
2. Yes, governor limits always apply. You will need to make sure that your code is properly bulkified, though with batch Apex you can also control the batch size (default is 200 records per transaction.)

This does have a few caveats:

1. The processing will be completed asynchronously, not while the user waits.
2. There is a limit to the number of batches that can be queued at a time (currently 5, I think.) If this process is initiated by regular users a good approach would be to store their requests in a custom object. The batch could then query for new requests and process them together.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, Mike. Could you please see this scenario and help me understand the governor limits better?

I am going to use Batch Apex to process the opportunities further. However, I do need to give the user a way to identify the opportunities the batch will process. So, here is what I was thinking:

1. I would let the users use the standard Opportunities views to select the opportunities they want to process. I would add a mass update button on the opportunities view which will set a custom field on the Opportunity object. **So, my only followup- question is, what happens if the Opportunity view the user selected, returns more than 50,000 records? Will my custom Apex code to update the field bomb?**
2. A Batch Apex process will run in the evenings to further process those opportunities that have been identified by the user in the day and then reset the flag.